# Setting a location on a map and moving in a text based map

Tags: java, dictionary, multidimensional-array, direction

So I am very new to working with java and I am struggling with 2d arrays for maps or dungeons for a text based game. This is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Map
{ 
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("You have fallen into the dungeon");

    String [] Roomtiles = 
    {
          "You are at the entrance and may only go North.",
          "You are at the begining of the hallway, here you may go North, South, East, West.",
          "This is an achient room, the only way is East.",
          "This is an old storage, the only way is West.",
          "The hallway continues North or South.",
          "You reach a cornor and may go only West or South.",
          "You reach a room with a window, the exits are East and West.",
          "You reach a room with a massive door"    
    };

    String[] currentRoom = Roomtiles = 0;

    //North = 0, East = 1, South = 2, West = 3       
    int[][] Exits =
    {
        {1,-1,-1,-1},
        {4,3,0,2},
        {-1,1,-1,-1},
        {-1,-1,-1,1},
        {5,-1,1,-1},
        {-1,-1,4,6},
        {-1,5,-1,7},
        {-1,6,-1,-1},
    };
    System.out.printf(currentRoom);
  }
}
```

I have mapped out how I want the dungeon to look but I have no idea how to, for starters, set the location of the user and state their location, and I furthermore have no idea how I can make the user move through the map, the most I know is I need to make them use cardinal directions (like typing n for north, s for south, ext.) , but I have no idea how to branch out to implement this.